# Get XPath to attribute

Tags: python, xml, xpath, attributes, lxml

I want to get the actual XPath expression to an attribute node for a specific attribute in an xml element tree (using lxml).

Suppose the following XML tree.

```
<foo>
  <bar attrib_name="hello_world"/>
</foo>
```

The XPath expression "//@*[local-name() = "attrib_name"]" produces ['hello_world'] which is the values of concerned attributes, and "//@*[local-name() = "attrib_name"]/.." gets me the bar element, which is one level too high, I need the xpath expression to the specific attribute node itself, not its parent xml node, that is having the string 'attrib_name' I want to generate '/foo/bar/@attrib_name'.

```py
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

f = StringIO('<foo><bar attrib_name="hello_world"></bar></foo>')
tree = etree.parse(f)

print(tree.xpath('//@*[local-name() = "attrib_name"]'))
# --> ['hello_world']
print([tree.getpath(el) for el in tree.xpath('//@*[local-name() = "attrib_name"]/..')])
# --> ['/foo/bar']
```

As an add-on this should work with namespaces too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the /.. then you will get the [_ElementUnicodeResult](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult-class.html)

This will allow you to append the attribute name to the xpath:

```
>>> print(['%s/@%s' % (tree.getpath(attrib_result.getparent()), attrib_result.attrname) for attrib_result in tree.xpath('//@*[local-name() = "attrib_name"]')])
['/foo/bar/@attrib_name']
```

Trying to apply that to namespaces will result in the namespace added to the xpath (which may not be what you want):

```
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO('<foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><bar xsi:attrib_name="hello_world"></bar></foo>'))
>>> print(['%s/@%s' % (tree.getpath(attrib_result.getparent()), attrib_result.attrname) for attrib_result in tree.xpath('//@*[local-name() = "attrib_name"]')])
['/foo/bar/@{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}attrib_name']
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I would like to have the namespace not expanded, i.e. ['/foo/bar/@xsi:attrib_name'] would be the desired result.

Comment: You could replace it in the string, using nsmap. Using the xsi: prefix in the xpath would only work if you also pass in the namespace map to the xpath function: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: Yep, this is how I did it, thank you for your answer.